# How to make a black-and-red line in highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am using the [Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/demo) plugin to make graphs for a production area I am computerizing.

I made a jsFiddle of a sample graph:

http://jsfiddle.net/ericfarrow/j3s1xphu/1/

Now, as you can see in this line it is all just one solid blue line.

What I am being requsted by my users is to have:

a) Line color to be **black** for an UP inclination
b) Line color to be **red** for a DOWN inclination

Obviously I can change the default color for the line to black - however that doesn't really resolve it either.

I checked all the Highcharts docs and could not find a simple way to have the line dynamically change from one color to a different color depending on the UP/DOWN value of the line.

Anybody have any ideas on this?

Or maybe a different plugin that would provide this functionality?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not a direct way to do this.

The traditional method has been to use two different `series`, as here:

```
series: [{
            id:'up',
            index:0,
            name: 'Phil',
            color:'rgb(0,0,0)',
            marker: { enabled: false },
            data: [[0,100.0], [1,800.0],[1.5,null], [2,400.5], [3,1200.5], [4,1450.2], [5,1805.0],[5.5,null], [6,600.2], [7,750.5], [8,945.3], [9,1000.3], [10,1305.9]]
},{
            id: 'down',
            name: 'down',
            linkedTo:'up',
            index:1,
            color:'rgb(240,0,0)',
            marker: { enabled: false },
            data: [[1,800],[2,400.5],[3,null],[5,1805],[6,600.2],[7,null],[10,1305.9],[11,1050.6]]
}]
```

Example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/j3s1xphu/4/

There is also a plugin that looks like it does what you want, here:

- http://www.highcharts.com/plugin-registry/single/33/Multicolor%20series

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I needed. Been looking how to do this for far too long...